# How to show rational functions on quasiprojective variety is a sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am using the following definition with the following remark:
Definition Let $X$ be a quasi-projective algebraic set.
(1) A function $\phi: X \rightarrow k$ is regular if locally around every point $x \in X$ it is given by $\frac{F}{G}$ for homogeneous polynomials $F$ and $G$ of the same degree. The set of regular functions, denoted by $k[X]$, is a ring.
(2) Suppose that $X$ is irreducible, i.e. a quasi-projective variety. A rational function $\phi$ : $X \rightarrow k$ is the equivalence class of a pair $(U, \phi)$, where $U \subset X$ is non-empty and open, and $\phi \in k[U]$ is a regular function. Two pairs $(U, \phi)$ and $(V, \psi)$ are equivalent if there is some non-empty open subset $W \subset U \cap V$ with $\left.\phi\right|_W=\left.\psi\right|_W$. The set of rational functions, denoted by $k(X)$, is a field.

Remark Let $X$ be a quasi-projective variety. Then any rational function $\phi \in k(X)$ can be written as fraction $\phi=\frac{F}{G}$ where $F$ and $G$ are homogeneous polynomials of the same degree with $G \neq 0$. Note however that this description is not unique, i.e. a single rational function might have several descriptions as such a fraction.

Consider the presheaf $\mathcal{K}$ on $X$ whose sections on a non-empty open subset $U \subset X$ are given by
$$
\mathcal{K}(U)=\{f: U \rightarrow k \mid f \text { is a rational function }\}
$$
Show that $\mathcal{K}$ is a sheaf.

Since we are assuming this is already a presheaf, it is not necessary to show that. As for the two sheaf properties, if we use the definition given by the remark, it is clear that if the restriction of a rational function to a open subset is 0, then the original rational function must be 0. So the only tricky part is to show the gluing property of sheaves and this is where I am having trouble.

The gluuing property as stated by Hartshorne is:  if $U$ is an open set, if $\left\{V_i\right\}$ is an open covering of $U$, and if we have elements $s_i \in \mathscr{F}\left(V_i\right)$ for each $i$, with the property that for each $i, j,\left.s_i\right|_{V_i \cap V_j}=$ $\left.s_j\right|_{V_i \cap V_j}$, then there is an element $s \in \mathscr{F}(U)$ such that $\left.s\right|_{V_i}=s_i$ for each $i$. (Note condition (3) implies that $s$ is unique.)

So if we have an open cover $U_i$, then we can simply define our global function to be that whose restriction to each $U_i$ is the given section, but how do we get a global rational function out of that because our cover may not even be finite?

Edit: I would like to ask if the remark given may be a possible mistake and might only apply to irreducible varieties.

Comment: it seems your definition of a rational function is not the correct one: If $(U,\phi), (V,\psi)$ are two "pairs", we say they are equivalent iff $\phi_X =\psi_W$ where $W:=U \cap V$. You may have confused this with the definition of the stalk and the ring of  germs of functions defined at a point $p$.